# How can I add row on button click on specific row of table?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to add button on each row when i click on the add more button it should add new row after that row of input fields

```
var counter = 1;
function addInput(divName){
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Kindly add complete code..Provided code does not make any sense without markup...Also care to ask what is not working/expected output....

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;
  
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
  var element2 = document.createElement("input");
  element2.type = "text";
  element2.name = "txtbox[]";
  cell3.appendChild(element2);
}
```

```html
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
  <TR>
    <TD> 1 </TD>
    <TD> <INPUT type="text" /> </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this:

<button type="button" id="add-row">Add Row</button>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>name</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
var id = 2; 
var row = '<tr><td>'+id+'</td><td>name</td></tr>';
$('#add-row').click(function(){
    $('tbody').apppend(row);
    id++;
});
</script>
```